# I am trying to create a drop down menu which stores items from a restaurant menu, using vanilla JavaScript by passing it an array of objects

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting no errors but when I click the drop down menu I want it to display the name of the item and the price.

Instead it just displays [object Object].

I have tried appending itemList.item[i] but get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

```
/*

///Food Items 

*/
/*Constructor which stores the items on the menu*/
function Item (item, price) {
    this.item = item;
    this.price = price;
}

var iOne = new Item('Peene Primviera', 14.60);
var iTwo = new Item('Fillet Steak', 20.00);
var iThree = new Item('Fillet Steak', 20.00);



var foodSelection = document.getElementById('menu');
var itemList = [
    {iOne},
    {iTwo},
    {iThree}
];

var itemName = itemList.name;

//Add the Options to the DropDownList.
for (var i = 0; i <= itemList.length; i++) {
    foodSelection.options.add(new Option(itemList[i]));
};
```

The result I want is just to display the name of the item and the price of the item in the drop down list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `[Object object]` is there because you convert an `object` to a `string`
which is done by calling `Object.toString()` returning `[Object object]` by defaul

There are some problems in your code, see the comment in the snippets

```js
/*

///Food Items 

*/
/*Constructor which stores the items on the menu*/
function Item (item, price) {
    this.item = item;
    this.price = price;
}

var iOne = new Item('Peene Primviera', 14.60);
var iTwo = new Item('Fillet Steak', 20.00);
var iThree = new Item('Fillet Steak', 20.00);


var foodSelection = document.getElementById('menu');
var itemList = [
    iOne, // you don't need to surround these with {}
    iTwo,
    iThree
];

var itemName = itemList.name;

for (var i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) { // here using <= is not good because i goes to 3 while your index goes up to 2 (start at 0)
    var item = itemList[i]
    var value = item.item + " (" + item.price +")"
    foodSelection.options.add(new Option(value));
    // by default creating a string from a object create [Object object]
    // so you need to create the string yourself
};
```

```html
<select id="menu"></select>
```

as mention by [`ths`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6388552/ths) in comments, replacing

```js
for (var i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {...}
```

by

```js
var count = itemList.length
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {...}
```

give some better performance as the second expression in for loop is recalculated every time **BUT** you seem to be starting with js and don't need to be preocupated by this unless you loop over thousands of elements

---

another way to do it is to create a `toString` in `Item`

```js
/*

///Food Items 

*/
/*Constructor which stores the items on the menu*/
function Item (item, price) {
    this.item = item;
    this.price = price;
    this.toString = function() {
      return this.item + " (" + this.price +")"
    }
}

var iOne = new Item('Peene Primviera', 14.60);
var iTwo = new Item('Fillet Steak', 20.00);
var iThree = new Item('Fillet Steak', 20.00);


var foodSelection = document.getElementById('menu');
var itemList = [
    iOne,
    iTwo,
    iThree
];

var itemName = itemList.name;

for (var i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
    var item = itemList[i]
    foodSelection.options.add(new Option(item));
    // calling item.toString() behind the hood
};
```

```html
<select id="menu"></select>
```

Comment: *"here using <= is not good because i goes to 3..."* also it's better to store the `array`'s length in a variable.

Comment: @ths you mean the array's length ?

Comment: yeah absolutely, sorry my bad !

Comment: @ths It can be an idea to tell even if he seems to be starting and if I do this I might as well talk about `forEach`

Comment: just a performance optimization. Anyway, i used `forEach` in my answer.

Comment: @ths the main difference between our answer is you optimize these things while I try to keep the code style as close as possible to his (good answer btw)

Comment: Thank you all for answering so fast its my first time using stack overflow and I rely appreciate the help. I was trying all sorts and getting no were :).

Comment: @Liam your question is a really good one, it make one want to answer it.
continue making question as clean as this one and you'll have an answer most of the time.
Don't forget to check the answer who helped you the most as validated

Answer (score 2):

`ItemList[i]` will return an Item object. You now want to display the name of that object (which I believe is the item attribute). So you have a list of Item objects, you can use array notation to index elements inside of that. However trying to index `ItemList.item[i]` would not make any sense, unless ItemList was an object containing and item attribute that was an array.
I would try this line:

`foodSelection.options.add(new Option(itemList[i].item));`

Note that this will only display the item name. Now you need to append the price onto it.

`foodSelection.options.add(new Option(itemList[i].item +" " +itemList[i].price));`

You also will need to make a change to how you are adding Objects to your ItemList Array.

```
var itemList = [
    {iOne},
    {iTwo},
    {iThree}
];
```

This is essentially saying you want an array of objects that contain an Item object inside of them. In other words, you do not want to surround the elements of the array with `{}` the object notation indicators.

In stead, populate your array like so:

```
var itemList = [
    iOne,
    iTwo,
    iThree
];
```

Comment: This will not work: `itemList[i].item` does not exist due to `{iOne}` inside the array

Comment: @empiric can you elaborate on what you mean by that?  Is this because he is declaring iOne as an object inside of the array even though it is already an object?

Comment: @plum0 yes exactly this

Comment: Exactly, so inside the loop you could access the string via `itemList[i].iOne.item`, but that wouldn't make much sense as you would have to have a variable index

Comment: @empiric Thanks so much! Such a small concept I overlooked when typing this answer. Made the edits accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is surrounding the instances of the `Item` class into `{` and `}` (`{iOne}`), this actually will create a new object that has one attribute named the same as the variable name (`{iOne}` => `iOne` is the attribute's name) thus there's no attribute called `0`.

In order to bypass that, you'll simply populate the `itemList` array without the curly braces like so :

```
var itemList = [
    iOne,
    iTwo,
    iThree
];
```

And now you can iterate through that array as usuall :

```js
/*Constructor which stores the items on the menu*/
function Item(item, price) {
  this.item = item;
  this.price = price;
}

const iOne = new Item('Peene Primviera', 14.60),
  iTwo = new Item('Fillet Steak', 20.00),
  iThree = new Item('Fillet Steak', 20.00),
  foodSelection = document.getElementById('menu'),
  itemList = [
    iOne,
    iTwo,
    iThree
  ];

itemList.forEach(i => {
  const o = document.createElement('option');
  o.value = i.price;
  o.textContent = `${i.item} ${i.price}$`;
  foodSelection.options.add(o);
});
```

```html
<select id="menu"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip I appreciate it allot very helpful have a nice day

Answer (score -1):

`new Option` expects strings and you are passing in an object. Reference the text

```
foodSelection.options.add(new Option(itemList[i].item));
```

and if you want the value

```
var opt = itemList[i]
foodSelection.options.add(new Option(opt.item, opt.price));
```

Comment: This will not work: `itemList[i].item` does not exist due to `{iOne}` inside the array